# OpenNI 2 set min/max depth values

Tags: openni

I am making a C++ utility that uses OpenNI 2. Ideally I now need to set the minimum and the maximum thresholds for the depth image. I did this in the past with OpenCV or my own image processing functions and before going this way again I am wondering whether there's a feature in OpenNI that supports this natively.

Having a look to the downloadable documentation (comes with the OpenNI package) there's a couple of interesting functions defined in the class VideoStream in *OpenNI.h*. These are:

```
int VideoStream::getMinPixelValue()
int VideoStream::getMaxPixelValue()
```

which return the current limits I need; these seem to be **hardware readings** though. Nonetheless, the VideoStream class exposes also the **setProperty** function which allows setting one of the properties in the list of values defined in *oniProperties.h*.

Since neither the documentation nor the comments in that file specify if one property is read only or not, I tried to write the min and max values by doing

```
myVideoStream.setProperty<int>(openni::STREAM_PROPERTY_MIN_VALUE, myIntMinValue);
myVideoStream.setProperty<int>(openni::STREAM_PROPERTY_MAX_VALUE, myIntMaxValue);
```

As a result the values **do not change**.

My questions are:

1. **Do you confirm that min and max pixel values in the VideoStream are read only?**
2. **Does OpenNI, in some way, support natively of setting these thresdolds?**

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: have you found an answer till now?

Comment: No, unfortunately. In OpenNI there seems to be no way to set those thresholds at the source. You have to operate through OpenCV or make your own threshold filter.

Answer (score 1):

I'm facing a similar issue, i.e., setting the maxDepthVlaue of a particular device. The status always return as a failure. However, when you run isPropertySupported(openni::STREAM_PROPERTY_MAX_VALUE), it returns true. So there is an internal means to set the max depth value. Don't quite know what that is though.